# Squaring a basis = basis?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $b_1, \dots, b_n$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ with positive entries, i.e. $b_1, \dots, b_n \in \mathbb R_{>0}^n$.

Is it then true that the following vectors

$$
\begin{pmatrix}  (b_1^{(1)})^2 \\ (b_1^{(2)})^2 \\ \vdots \\ (b_1^{(n)})^2\end{pmatrix}, \dots, \begin{pmatrix}  (b_n^{(1)})^2 \\ (b_n^{(2)})^2 \\ \vdots \\ (b_n^{(n)})^2\end{pmatrix} 
$$

is also a basis of $\mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Only for $n\le 2$. To get a counterexample for $n \ge 3$ start with a matrix with zero determinant and positive elements. Then take the matrix formed with the positive square roots. Almost all the time you will get a matrix with determinant $\ne 0$. Now square back.

Comment: Would work in char $2\ $...

Answer (score 1):

To expand on orangeskid’ comment, when $n=3$ you can use Pythagorean triples :
let 
$$
(b_1,b_2,b_3)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
p_1^2-q_1^2 & 2p_1q_1 & p_1^2+q_1^2 \\
p_2^2-q_2^2 & 2p_2q_2 & p_2^2+q_2^2 \\
p_3^2-q_3^2 & 2p_3q_3 & p_3^2+q_3^2 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

The matrix of squares will always have $(1,1,-1)$ in its kernel, but
for generic values of the $p_i$ and $q_i$, the above matrix will
be invertible. An example :

$$
(b_1,b_2,b_3)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 4 & 5 \\
5 & 12 & 13 \\
7 & 24 & 25 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: Integral...Crickey! +1